# Inconsistent evaluation on the result list of assignment operator in Perl?

Tags: perl, activeperl

The evaluation on the result list looks to be inconsistent in scalar and list context. As below code snippet shows, the left side of assignment operation (=) is evaluated in list context, but the list in the right side is evaluated when in scalar context. Is this expected and any language principle to explain this behavior?

```
print (($k, $v) = (3, 4, 5)); # output is 34
print scalar (($k, $v) = (3, 4, 5)); # output is 3
```

Comment: This is an interesting quirk. You can get the expected behaviour if you insert an array before the list of scalars, e.g. `print scalar(@a = ($k,$v) = ...)`

Comment: @TLP, yes, the extra assignment to @a works as expected since the last evaluated assignment operator is the one following @a, and the left side and right side of it are exactly the same. It is a little tricky to keep this in mind.

Comment: what is the *expected behaviour* you are talking about?

Comment: @ysth The output should be 2, and not 3. `($k, $v)` should return 2 in scalar context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't inconsistent so much as doing something completely different.

Every operator in perl has a defined behaviour in list and scalar context, and they often are quite different.  In the case of a list assignment, in list context, it returns its left operand, while in scalar context it returns a count of elements in its right operand.

Note that this meaning makes things like this work:

```
while ( my ($k,$v) = each %hash ) {
```

Comment: I think the point is that `scalar` should have returned `2`, since the resulting list is 2 elements long.

Comment: @TLP: and my point is that context doesn't work on values, it works on operations.  it isn't the case that the list assignment executes and then the result is given scalar context; the list assign is itself context-sensitive.

Comment: @ysth, it makes sense that the operator is context sensitive, and it is common that the same expression returns different value based on the context, but usually these values are related, and array and its length. Even if it is by design that given routine could return any unrelated value, I think there may be reason for such design. Like work around some issue, as while loop you mentioned. Is making while loop working the sole reason to create such inconsistent semantics?

Comment: the reason is that it is useful behaviour, in that and in other cases

Comment: Interesting observation about `while`

Answer (score 4):

It is simply a matter of the semantics being *defined* that way.

This is from [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators)

> Similarly, a list assignment in list context produces the list of
>       lvalues assigned to, and a list assignment in scalar context returns the
>       number of elements produced by the expression on the right hand side of
>       the assignment.